# Реализовать функции, которая принимает один из объектов и возвращает его тип не используя оператор instanceof

Tags: javascript, ооп, объекты, prototype

Даны сущности Dog, Cat, Woodpecker, которые являются наследниками сущности Animal. Animal содержит свойства age, name, sound, region и метод say. Dog, Cat, Woodpecker не содержит явно данных свойств, но наследует их у Animal. Также они содержат метод goAway.

Реализовать функции getTypep(), которая принимает один из объектов Dog, Cat, Woodpecker и возвращает его тип не используя оператор instanceof, а проверяя наличие свойств/методов объектов.

Есть 2 варианта решения, это проверка объекта конструктора, к примеру, cat.constructor === Cat, или же у Animal переопределить метод toString, который будет возвращать имя конструктора. Но мне кажется, что это не то, что просят в условии.

Comment: в ES2015 у `Function` добавилось свойство `name`, поэтому достаточно будет `obj.constructor.name`. Но задача слишком неконкретна, к ней был приложен какой-нибудь код?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Решил задачу следующим способом :
'function getType(obj) {
                if(Cat.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj)){
                    return 'Cat';
                }else if(Dog.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj)){
                  return 'Dog';
             }else if(Woodpecker.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj)){
                    return 'Woodpecker';
                }
        }'

Спасибо за отклик.

Comment: По условию, задача скорее всего подразумевает использования метода "утки" - если объект ведет себя как утка, крякает, ходит - значит это утка!!!!! Иными словами, необходимо проверять специфические свойства и методы объекта.